# Odd/Even background color over image

Tags: html, css

I've been having this issue with nth-childs trying to make every other card to have a certain color on it. Tried a bunch of solutions but having issues making them stick. I believe it's the way I am attacking the nth-childs. The idea is to have the .layer cover the parent element with a gradient cover over a certain background image.

```css
.form-wrap:nth-child(odd) .layer {
  background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-wrap col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="upper">
  <div class="action">
        <div class="table" style="background-image: url('url');"> 
          <h3 class="page-headline">Text</h3>
          <div class="layer"></div>
        <div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please revise your question? I'm not sure I understand the issue

Comment: I would like the .layer (which is supposed to layered on top of the parent element for a slightly transparent gradient) to change colors every odd or even depending on the css. Don't believe I have the nth-child setup correct.

Comment: Then your example doesn't represent the question, as it only has one `.layer` element